# How to make a form with a subform for many-to-many association in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Basically I'd like to do something like this:
[image]

Only in my situation I want a `User` to be able to sign up for many `Disciplines` with a single form.

What would be the right way of making the form so that I could let the person click in `checkboxes` what kind of disciplines he/she wants to take part in?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using rails [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in combination with ryanb's [nested form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem.

From the documentation:

> Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records
>   through the parent. By default nested attribute updating is turned off
>   and you can enable it using the **#accepts_nested_attributes_for** class
>   method. When you enable nested attributes an attribute writer is
>   defined on the model.

At a high level, you would define your classes like so:

```
class Employee
  has_many :orders
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders

end

class Order
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but the given `gem` only works on rails 3